# Adding href to panda .read_html DF

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a table with the information available on this [website](http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/resolutions.php?st=5&f=2016). I want the table to have 3 columns: 0 series/date, 1 title and 2 links. I already managed to get the first two columns but I don't know how to get the link for each entry.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/resolutions.php?st=5&f=2016"
r = requests.get(url)
df_list = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = df_list[0]
df.head()
```

[image: output]

Will it be possible to get what I want by only using pandas?

Comment: can you post the expected output, I'm not what what the `links` columns is suppose to look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible with pandas only. It can be done with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), though:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://legislaturautuado.com/pgs/resolutions.php?st=5&f=2016"
r = requests.get(url)

html_table = BeautifulSoup(r.text).find('table')
r.close()

df = pd.read_html(str(html_table), header=0)[0]
df['Link'] = [link.get('href') for link in html_table.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Good and simple combination of `pandas` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Can you explain me how `[0]` in line `df = pd.read_html(str(html_table), header=0)[0]` works to transform a list to a df? I also had `[0]` in my original code but I honestly don't know how the change to df occurs.

Comment: Hi @StevenGonzález, sure! If you read the pandas [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) documentation, you'll see that this function returns a list of dataframes. Therefore, we're not converting a list to a dataframe, we're actually extracting a dataframe from a list of dataframes (in this case, there's only one dataframe in the list, so we extract it with `[0]`).